# Create wiki pages on SharePoint with web services

Tags: windows, sharepoint, soap, wiki

With which methods do I create wiki content on SharePoint, using the provided web services?

I've searched the MSDN docs up and down - with no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create any list in SharePoint using the List.asmx web service.

That service has a method named AddList which takes 3 parameters:

1. Name - This is what your new list will be named.
2. Description - The description of your new list.
3. Template ID - This is an int that specifies the type of list to create.

In the case of a wiki - you will use Template ID 119.

The documentation only partially lists these template ID's.  A better list used to be [here](http://simeonlobo.wordpress.com/2008/02/27/sharepoint-list-template-ids/) (now a 404) and is now accessible through the [Internet Archive here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090210025338/http://simeonlobo.wordpress.com/2008/02/27/sharepoint-list-template-ids/).

NOTE: Use the URL property of the List web service to specify where the new list should be created.

Comment: Thanks for your very useful answer. The Template ids are a good help. Do you also know, what type a wiki page is? My Browser says in the URL bar: "CreateWebPage.aspx" So I assume, it is some kind of special Web Page. I'm still searching for the according service. Thanks so far!